# OSRM Table service returns empty array when I use a HTTP Server

Tags: table, open-source-routing-machine

I am currently trying to use OSRM's Table service to get the durations of the fastest routes between two points, to be able to build a time matrix using Python and later use it as a parameter in an optimization problem.

My problem is that whenever I run my own server through my jupyter notebook (using five different locations) the 'durations' array returns empty, like in the following example:

```
str_locations = '-30.59464,-71.19366;-30.60386,-71.21342;-30.58654,-71.18429;-30.60298,-71.20075;-30.58603,-71.19196'
r=requests.get('http://localhost:5000/table/v1/driving/'+str_locations+'?sources=0')
r.json()['durations'][0]
```

returns:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I've already checked that those points exist and are connected using the two first points in map.project-osrm.org (here's the [link](http://map.project-osrm.org/?z=15&center=-30.599041%2C-71.201577&loc=-30.595055%2C-71.194459&loc=-30.603906%2C-71.213390&hl=en&alt=0)). Plus, whenever I replace the local server with the online demo (http://router.project-osrm.org/) the array is not empty, but that doesn't work with more than 100 coordinates and I need at least 250.

I think it could have something to do with the algorithm that I am using, MLD rather than CH?

Comment: Can you share the exact query to the live server that works?

Comment: This is the query that works but returns an empty array `'http://localhost:5000/table/v1/driving/-30.59464,-71.19366;-30.60386,-71.21342;-30.58654,-71.18429;-30.60298,-71.20075;-30.58603,-71.19196?sources=0'`. And when I put it on the demo server like this: [link](http://router.project-osrm.org/table/v1/driving/-30.59464,-71.19366;-30.60386,-71.21342;-30.58654,-71.18429;-30.60298,-71.20075;-30.58603,-71.19196?sources=0) It says that there is no route between them. Those points all are situated in the same town and when I use the example query the same thing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your latitude and longitude are in the incorrect order.

For example, this query works:

http://router.project-osrm.org/table/v1/driving/-71.1936,-30.59464;-71.21342,-30.60386;-71.18429,-30.58654;-71.20075,-30.60298;-71.19196,-30.58603?sources=0

But it returns a bad response when the coordinate order is swapped.

Additionally, here's a different way to declare and use your lat/lon tuples in your code. Doing it with an array of a lat/long tuples makes it so that these kinds of errors are easier to fix, and your code is more generic.

```py
host = 'http://localhost:5000/'
path = 'table/v1/driving/'
waypoints = [(-30.59464,-71.19366),(-30.60386,-71.21342),(-30.58654,-71.18429),(-30.60298,-71.20075),(-30.58603,-71.19196)]
waypoints = ';'.join(map(lambda pt: '{},{}'.format(*reversed(pt)), waypoints))
r = requests.get('{}{}{}?sources=0'.format(host, path, waypoints))
```